# Tumblr Integration in ios

Tags: ios

I want to Integrate Tumbler in My app and also Want to share image on Tumblr.

I have demo for TumblrConnect which is on Github but I can not find proper way to Integrate Tumblr.

Only one Time Asking For Tumblr Login and Then When I tickMark Tumblr option image share on Logged in Account.

I went through Tumblr SDK project on Github, even after providing right credentials not able to login might be framework is outdated,

I'm unable to figure out how to integrate tumbler in iphone application.

Please help me.

Please give me code if anyone have working like this with Tumblr.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the full SDK and documentation of how to setup and integrate Tumblr in iOS (also for OSX) app.

https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/TMTumblrSDK/1.0.8/

Comment: I have seen this demo but its difficult to Integrate if any better option for Tumblr Integration.I have worked before 15 days so I have not exact idea exactly what is the problem/issue with this sdk so if it is possible any working demo so I can Integrate Tumblr Easily. Thnks for help :-)

Comment: That demo is provided from Tumblr official. I think however its tough enough, you should go with it and give a try. It may be painless but definitely handy once you'll get aware of it.